# Access properties in runtime with dynamic name using spring

Tags: java, spring, properties, spring-properties

I have a properties file that looks like this

```
server.se.host
server.se.port

server.us.host
server.us.port
```

and so on. It's a list of host/port used for different countries (Sweden and US in this example). These can also be set as environment variables in the form SERVER_SE_HOST and so on.

The code however, doesn't know what countries exists at build time so I need to dynamically find these variables, including the ones only available as environment variables at run time.

Ideally I'd like to get configration class with a dynamic prefix, something like

```
Config countrySpecificConfig = ConfigMagic.getFromPropertiesWithPrefix("server." + countryCode);
```

If that is not possible I would be happy with

```
String countrySpecificHost = PropertiesMagic.get("server." + countryCode + ".host"); 
String countrySpecificPort = PropertiesMagic.get("server." + countryCode + ".port");
```

but I haven't found a way to do that either.

Thanks.

Comment: Reading system environment variables can be done quite easily using `System#getenv`. As for what you want to achieve I suppose this is what you're looking for: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/support/PropertiesLoaderUtils.html

Comment: Yes, reading properties files is easy, so is reading environment variables. I'm trying to find a way to do "the spring magic" where variables are read from multiple sources and places with different priority.